# Common practice for validating classifiers in medical statistics

Tags: classification, cross-validation, bootstrap, validation

We are writing a paper, where we suggest a new classifier. We have a data base with about 1400 medical cases.

Would it be sufficient just to divide the dataset into training 70% and test 30%? Or should bootstrap be needed? May be, 10-fold cross validation will be considered more preferable?

I am not asking about advantages and drawbacks of each procedure. I am asking about common practice only.

Comment: For some reason I love leave-one-out cross validation - if you have enough computational power, do it. At least you'd convince me as a reviewer =) however I am not a reviewer and hopefully more experienced members will answer this question.

Comment: If you are using a standard machine-learning approach  (SVM etc.) you will need to perform cross-validation during hyperparameter tuning. In this case using the same cross-validation loop to both determine optimal hyperparameters and to validate is misleading. In this case use nested cross-validation or validation on a hold-out sample (30% sounds fine given your sample size). The most convincing case imho: a) Train and cross-validate your model on the given retrospective data-set. b) Validate by testing prospectively in a newly obtained sample (but this is laborious, of course).

Comment: What kind of out-of-sample testing is common to your field or the journals to which you would submit? And @mzunhammer I think your comments about a cross-validation set and a true test set would make for a nice answer.

Comment: @Dave Bootstrap may be more common, but I have very little experience in that field of medicine. So I am asking about general trends in medical literature.

Comment: Eeeee.... you want to publish new classifier, but you no nothing about proper validation? This smells bad. Sorry for being bitch. 10-fold is just 10 cycles of training and validation. I'd like to see it repeated at least 10 times. I'd like to see some distribution. If you want to publish new method one data set is not enough. You need to run it on some pupular sets and compare to seminal scores. If you're not seminal, why bother publishing? Additionally, if you're using validation set in learning process, you need 3rd split for tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see in the current medical literature, both cross-validation or a validation based on a hold-out sample will likely get you published in OK, but not top journals (this may strongly depend on the standards in your sub-field, though). One caveat: If you are using a standard machine-learning approach (SVM etc.) you will have to perform  hyper-parameter tuning. Tuning usually requires cross-validation. You CANNOT use simple cross-validation to both select optimal hyperparameters and to validate your results. In this case use either have to rely on

a) [nested cross-validation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_nested_cross_validation_iris.html) (which sounds complicated, but is just the [Inception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inception) version of cross-validation ...)

or

b) validation in a hold-out sample that has not been looked at during training & parameter-tuning (30% sounds fine, given your sample size, but that depends on the performance of the classifier).

Cross-validation is arguably the "more powerful" approach (i.e. the one yielding better results), hold-out sample arguably the "cleaner" one.

However, the central point for the medical field is: "Will it help to improve the diagnosis of future cases in a real-world setting?" Therefore, the most convincing case IMHO (and the one most likely to attract top-journals): a) Train and cross-validate your model on the given retrospective data-set. b) Validate your classifier on data from a prospective validation study, that was specifically obtained for that purpose, with a pre-registered study-protocol (including the exact classifier to test), with analysts being blinded to the key validation criteria until classification, ideally covering multiple testing centers and multiple (sub-)populations, and ideally including data/tests that allow to identify mechanisms behind and potential confounders threatening the method. But this is laborious, of course.

Comment: I have a similar question in cross validation. Please let me know your thoughts on this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/439252/how-to-rank-data-based-on-cross-validation Thank you :)